# Insufficient memory when training multi-label classification model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm a student studying machine learning for several months.

**Goal**

I am currently trying to create a multi-label image classification model.

**Problem**

As the learning progresses, it consumes a large amount of memory and error is occurred.
Even though I only use about 500MB of data (about 50,000 images in total), the memory usage exceeds 32GB.
I suspect that there is something wrong with the dataset I prepared.

**What I tried**

I changed the batch size and switched to the implementation using Data Generator.

- about batch-size
  → After learning about 1/10 of the total number of steps. but I don't think it will complete the learning process even if I try setting it to 1.
- about DataGenerator
  → I got error: [ Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Failed precondition: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.]

**code**
※This is part of it.

```
import ~~~

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

def macro_f1(y, y_hat, thresh=0.5):
    y_pred = tf.cast(tf.greater(y_hat, thresh), tf.float32)
    tp = tf.cast(tf.math.count_nonzero(y_pred * y, axis=0), tf.float32)
    fp = tf.cast(tf.math.count_nonzero(y_pred * (1 - y), axis=0), tf.float32)
    fn = tf.cast(tf.math.count_nonzero((1 - y_pred) * y, axis=0), tf.float32)
    f1 = 2*tp / (2*tp + fn + fp + 1e-16)
    macro_f1 = tf.reduce_mean(f1)
    return macro_f1

def create_dataset(filenames, labels, is_training=True, total_cnt=0, batch_size=8, train_flag=False):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
    if train_flag:
        dataset = dataset.map(parse_function, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    else:
        dataset = dataset.map(parse_function_val, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.cache()
    if train_flag:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=total_cnt)
    dataset = dataset.repeat().batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset

def parse_function(filename, label):
    image_string = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
    image_resized = tf.image.resize(image_decoded, [224, 224])
    image_normalized = (image_resized / 255) -1
    image_aug = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image=image_normalized)
    image_aug = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image=image_aug)
    return image_aug, label

def parse_function_val(filename, label):
    image_string = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
    image_resized = tf.image.resize(image_decoded, [224, 224])
    image_normalized = (image_resized / 255) -1
    return image_normalized, label


def main():

    ~Abbreviation~

    # list for dataset
    a_train    = []
    b_train    = []
    c_train    = []
    image_list_train = []

    a_val   = []
    b_val   = []
    c_val   = []
    asphalt_val    = []
    image_list_val = []

    DATA_DIR = os.path.join(DIR, 'data')
    modes = ['train', 'val']
    classes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a_b', 'b_c', 'c_a', 'a_b_c'] #dir-name

    #make dataset
    for mode in modes:
        for class in classes:
            dir_path = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, mode, class)
            file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_path, '*'))
            file_list = sorted(file_list)

            for file_name in file_list:
                # Split the folder name (ex: a_b) by _ and 
                # label it according to whether it contains the letters a, b, c
                cls_list = cls_name.split('_')
                if 'a' in cls_list: a = 1
                else:               a = 0
                if 'b' in cls_list: b = 1
                else:               b = 0
                if 'c' in cls_list: c = 1
                else:               c = 0

                if mode == 'train':
                    a_train.append(a)
                    b_train.append(b)
                    c_train.append(c)
                    image_list_train.append(file_name)
                elif mode == 'val':
                    a_val.append(a)
                    b_val.append(b)
                    c_val.append(c)
                    image_list_val.append(file_name)
                else:
                    print('ERROR')

    num_train = len(image_list_train)
    num_val = len(image_list_val)

   # make label ex) [[0,0,1],[1,1,0],[0,1,0]]
    cls_id_train = []
    cls_id_val = []
    for i in range(num_train):
        cls_id_train.append([a_train[i], b_train[i], c_train[i]])
    for i in range(num_val):
        cls_id_val.append([a_val[i], b_val[i], c_val[i]])

    checkpoint_path = ckpt_dir + '/ckpt-{epoch}-{val_macro_f1:.2f}-{val_loss:.2f}'

    # make dataset
    train_ds = create_dataset(image_list_train,
                              cls_id_train,
                              total_cnt=num_train,
                              batch_size=batch_size,
                              train_flag=True,
                              )
    val_ds = create_dataset(image_list_val,
                            cls_id_val,
                            total_cnt=num_val,
                            batch_size=batch_size,
                            train_flag=False,
                            )

    # train
    IMG_SHAPE = (img_size, img_size, channels)
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                                include_top=False,
                                                weights='imagenet')
    global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
    prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_classes, activation='sigmoid')
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([base_model,global_average_layer,prediction_layer])
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=lr, momentum=momentum, nesterov=nesterov),loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[macro_f1])

    ckpt_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 monitor='val_macro_f1',
                                                 mode='max',
                                                 verbose=1)

    csv_logger = tf.keras.callbacks.CSVLogger(ckpt_dir+'/training.csv', separator=',')

    history = model.fit(train_ds,
                        steps_per_epoch= int(num_train//batch_size),
                        validation_data=val_ds,
                        validation_steps= int(num_val//batch_size),
                        shuffle=True,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        callbacks=[ckpt_cb, csv_logger],)

    model.save_weights(ckpt_dir + '/my_checkpoint')``
```

Comment: Welcome. I doesn't know a lots on this field but 50,000 sounds like a really large amount of data. As i know you can try to use services of Large Comanies(Like Amazon or Google) to run your code, it cost money but maybe you can have some discount(From the fact you are a student). Look also this link: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13901/machine-learning-best-practices-for-big-dataset

Answer (score 0):

Add this code snippet before your code, which will limit the memory growth in case if you are using Tensorflow-GPU version.

```
gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu[0], True)
```